# Smooth rotation in CSS keyframe animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

**How can I get this CSS 3 keyframe animation to look smoother?**

As is, the rotation appears to stop at 180deg. I would like it to complete the full 360deg rotation without stopping in the middle. Ideally, I would like it to speed up and slow down.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: like 2s 3s infinite;
  font-size: 40px;
}

@keyframes like {
  0% {
    transform: rotate( 0deg ) scale( 1 );
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotate( 15deg ) scale( 1 );
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate( -180deg ) scale( 1.4 );
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate( -360deg ) scale( 1 );
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="icon">
    &hearts;
</div>
```

*PS: Is it possible to specify a delay between iterations? I thought this could be achieved with the `3s`, but it appears to only get applied before the first iteration, not before subsequent ones?*

Answer (score 3):

Use `linear` and make the last state to take more time by adding more percentage  in order to simulate the delay between iterations:

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: like 2s 3s infinite linear;
  font-size: 40px;
}

@keyframes like {
  0% {
    transform: rotate( 0deg ) scale( 1 );
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotate( 15deg ) scale( 1 );
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate( -180deg ) scale( 1.4 );
  }
  80%,100% {
    transform: rotate( -360deg ) scale( 1 );
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="icon">
    &hearts;
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set individual timing functions on each keyframe.

Setting the keyframe that goes up to 180 deg as ease in make it start smoothly , but end with some speed.

Set the next keyframe to the opposite, and you will go through 180 without stopping, but still have the animation speed increase and decrease.

As Teman Afif answered, to get a pause between animations you need a keyframe properties applied to 2 different percentages.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: like 6s infinite linear;
  font-size: 40px;
}

@keyframes like {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    transform: rotate( 0deg ) scale( 1 );
  }
  25% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    transform: rotate( -180deg ) scale( 1.4 );
  }
  50%, 100% {
    transform: rotate( -360deg ) scale( 1 );
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="icon">
    &hearts;
</div>
```